# ubuntu super slow boot with error message ata3.00 revalidation failed (errno=-5)

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 23.10 boots super slowly. The following error and warning messages appear after roughly 2 minutes of black screen.

[image]

Then the login screen appears. Kernel version is 6.5.0-14. How to fix this?